# The error of Django application crashed ngnix and the server

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, amazon-lightsail

My Django application run well for a while, then I got `502 Bad Gateway`, after a few hours, I am unable to ping the domain and use SSH to connect my server(from Amazon Lightsail). My other application served by ngnix was also not available then. While if I didn't start the Django application, ther application served by ngnix would run steadily. So I guess it is the error of my Django application crashed ngnix and the server.

After rebooting the server for serveral times, the server seems recovered then I can ping the domain and use SSH to connect the server. But after a while, the same problem would occurs again. I wonder how to fix the problem.

Some diagnostic information since the start of the Django application to the end of the Nginx server provided below.

1. The RAM usage is high during the process.

   [image]

2. The uwsgi log. https://bpa.st/FP7Q
3. The Nginx error log. https://bpa.st/35EQ

Comment: Do you have any redirects when landing on the home page?

Comment: @Daniel No. The two domains to my server are `blue-kingfisher.com` and `mathjoy.ml`